# Keyboard repeat on Input Director slave machine

Tags: windows, input-director

I'm using [Input Director](http://www.inputdirector.com/) as a software KVM to control my laptop from my desktop, and all is almost OK with the setup.  However, key-presses on the master keyboard seem to repeat very easily on the slave, and it is close to impossible to type a word on the slave without getting repeated characters.  I typed the word 'repeat' on the master keyboard and my editor on the slave captured the characters 'repeeaatt'.

Both machines are Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input Director is a **great utility**. I would recommend it for anyone. That said, it isn't without its faults. I too have experience problems with it. My recommendation is to uninstall it completely, reboot the system, and reinstall it. Do this on both systems. This is how I have fixed my issues with it in the past. Before reinstalling it, make sure you have the most up-to-date version too.

*Note: Make sure that you do not have multiple instants of Input Director running by checking the system tray on both systems.*

Comment: I only installed it yesterday, from the latest version. :-(

Comment: I kind of figured you had the latest version. I still suggest that you uninstall, reboot, and then reinstall.

Comment: depending on your need you also could try [Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/) as an alternative, FWIW

Comment: Synergy is more buggy, in my experience. Windows OS to Windows OS, Input Director is better.  Use **Revo Uninstaller** to scrub your system when uninstalling.